# How to create lines and update legend in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am looking to create vertical lines indicating a monthly average, which a legend that will update each iteration with the new month. Here is what I have so far:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(2, 15), ylim=(10, 80))

month_avg = [6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4]
months = ['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J']

line = ax.plot([], [], alpha = 0.25)

ax.set_title('Running time per distance')
ax.set_xlabel('Distance (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('Elapsed Time (min)')

legend = ax.legend()

def animate(i):
    for i in range(0, i + 1):
        for j in range(len(months)):
            line.set_data([month_avg[j], month_avg[j]], [15,75])
            line.set_label(months[j])
    ax.remove()
    legend = ax.legend()
    return line

anim2 = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=7, interval=1000, repeat=False, blit = True)
plt.show()
```

When I run this code I don't get any output at all. Anyone know what I need to do to get it to work? Running in jup notebook.

Comment: What are the values in `month_avg` list? Are they distances in km, elapsed times in min or something else?

Comment: What do you want to see changing frame by frame? Do you want to add a line for a specific month at each iteration?

Comment: My intended outcome was a vertical line that went from min y to max y going through month average. Then on the next iteration I wanted the previous month line to drop and a new one to be added for the next month avg